# passing querystring parameters

Tags: asp.net

what is the best way of passing querystring to another page, i would definitly avoid like using.......

```
<a href="Page2.aspx?WONumber=12345">
```

is there any better way?

i was thinking create a Baseclass with few prop and update the baseclass?

thanks.

Comment: better in waht sense? like the guys say is your concern with the above route security, generalisability, the fact you have no strong typing, the fact you;re defining the name of your parameters in multiple places... any "better" solution depends on what the problem is to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encrypt a querystring parameter, if security is your concern.

Or you can use other holders, such s p.cambell says above (session & cookie).

You could also store it in a database, and have the page you go to retrieve it onload.

Just depends on your application requirements.

Another thing I've done is to use `<asp:panel>`, basically using a single page as though it were multiple pages.  In this way, I also have access to viewstate to hold my variables.  (Whenever a user clicks 'next', or whatever they would click to goto the next page, I simply hide the panel they're on, and show the panel they want to go to [visible = true/false] property)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to take the querystring argument, and use it in subsequent pages.

If it's not desirable to pass-forward this querystring argument from your current page, perhaps it's called `page1.aspx`, without using another querystring parameter, you could:

- store the value in `Session`. Consider `Session["WoNumber"] = Request.QueryString["WONumber"].ToString();`
- store the value in `Cookies`. You could use something like: `Response.Cookies["WoNumber"].Value = Request.QueryString["WONumber"].ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on where you're getting the value from. You can build a URL using `UriBuilder` or if it's simple enough string concatenation could be OK (though you'd have to make sure to `Server.UrlEncode` the values).

If the value is a constant, as your example implies, then there is nothing wrong with putting it directly into a query string, although I would still use a proper named constant, eg.

```
<a href="Page2.aspx?WONumber=<%= TheMagicOrderNumber %>
```

with the constant defined in the code-behind:

```
protected const int TheMagicOrderNumber = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objection is the maintainability of "magic string" URLS, and you'd be prepared to use a button instead of an anchor, you could do worse than

```
<form method="GET" action="Page2.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="WONumber" value="12345" />
    <input type="submit" value="Navigate" />
</form>
```

this method will generalise to a query string of any complexity with any number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article I came across a few months ago when I was looking for enhanced security with querystrings...

http://devcity.net/Articles/47/1/encrypt_querystring.aspx

It's a very good article, and has a bonus the author offers code examples in C# and VB.NET.

There are times when I prefer to use querystrings over sessions... small number of session objects is ok, but too many and it starts to become a bit tedious to debug problems.